# Example of a strongly dense set which is not ultrastrongly dense.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $B(H)$ denote the Banach space of bounded operators on $H$. Then there are several topologies we can endow on $B(H)$. I am interested in the case of the strong operator topology and and the ultrastrong operator topology (sometimes also called $\sigma$-strong).

Note that the ultrastrong topology is finer than the strong topology. If a set $X$ is ultrastrongly dense, then it is of course also strongly dense. I am having trouble coming up with a counter-example for the converse.

Does anyone have a simple example of a set which is strongly dense, but fails to be ultrastrongly dense? I would also be interested in similar examples for weak/ultraweakly dense sets.

From Martin Argerami's answer below, it seems like no such example exists at least when $X$ is a $*$-algebra. I am still interested in the case where $X$ is merely a set with no additional structure.

---

For the sake of completeness, the two topologies can be defined as follows. For each $\xi \in H$, let $\|\cdot \|_\xi$ be the semi-norm on $B(H)$ defined by
$$\|T\|_\xi = \|T\xi\|.$$
Then the strong operator topology is the topology induced by the collection of semi-norms $\{\|\cdot \|_\xi\}_{\xi\in H}$. Likewise, if we are given a sequence of vectors $s=(\xi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|\xi_n\|^2 < \infty,$$
we can define the semi-norm $\|\cdot \|_s$ by
$$\|T\|_s = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|T\xi_n\|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$
The ultrastrong topology is then the topology induced by the collection $\{\|\cdot \|_s\}$, where $s$ is an arbitrary $L^2$-convergent sequence.

Answer (score 2):

No such example exists, since the strong and ultra-strong topologies agree on bounded sets. Suppose that  $X\subset B(H)$ is strong dense, and fix $a\in B(H)$. Then there exists $\{x_j\}\subset X$ with $x_j\to a$ strongly. By Kaplansky's Density Theorem, we may assume that $\{x_j\}$ is bounded by $\|a\|$. On the ball $B_{\|a\|}(0)$ the two topologies agree, so $x_j\to a$ ultrastrongly. Thus $X$ is ultrastrong dense.

Comment: This is great. I suspected this to be true, but couldn't prove it, so I started looking for counter-examples. I was missing the usage of Kaplanski's. Thank you!

Comment: A follow-up question. Kaplanski's density theorem seems to require that $X$ is a $C^*$-algebra. How do I conclude the existence of a bounded net when $X$ is just a set?

Comment: For Kaplansky you don't need a C$^*$-algebra, just a $*$-algebra. But you are right, if $X$ is just a set my argument does not apply.

Comment: Do you know if the result continues to hold for a set?

Comment: We need to argue that $x_j$ is uniformly bounded, and the claim follows. To do so, we can appeal to the uniform boundedness principle. Since $x_j\to a$ strongly, $\sup_j\|x_j\xi\|<\infty$ for all $\xi\in H$. So, appealing to the Uniform boundedness principle, it follows that $\sup_j\|x_j\|<\infty$.

Comment: That's not true. Unbounded convergent sot nets exist.